# After upgrade to 4.7.13, I get 500 Internal Server Error when creating new mailing

Tags: drupal, error, 4.7, ajax

After upgrading from 4.7.11 to 4.7.13 (with Drupal 7.51), I get à 500 error (Internal Server Error) on an ajax call when attempting to create a new mailing. The screen stucks at "Initializing..."

- The message in the console is :  GET XHR
  http://dev.lists.sciences-po.fr/fr/civicrm/ajax/rest    [HTTP/1.1 500
  Internal Server Error 381 ms]
- Parameters are : action=get&entity=MailingGroup&json={"mailing_id":"6"}
- There are some similar ajax call before
  and after the faulty one, without any problem.
- There are no javascript error except this one.
- There are no group in the civicrm_mailing_group table

Have you got an idea of debug tests I could run to understand more about this error ? I know, I definitely need to read the server logs, but I don't have access.

Thanks for your help.

Philippe

Answer (score 2):

After investigations :

- The issue is due to i18n : if multilingual is on, then the bug raises. When it's off, there are no bug.
- CRM_Core_DAO_AllCoreTables::registerEntityType returns only table names without language code. In my case, the function returns civicrm_group instead of civicrm_group_fr_FR. Then, the function CRM_Core_DAO_AllCoreTables::getClassForTable($table) returns nothing, which ends with the following error : PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /store/www/dev.lists.sciences-po.fr/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/SQL.php on line 53

Guess some hook in the i18n module is missing or not working properly.